# SonarQube Java plugin custom rule: I want to do my own log settings by logback.xml

Tags: java, logging, plugins, rule

I have created a custom rules for Java using the / plugins / java-custom-rules.
I have made ​​a java-custom-rules plugin, it was able to run the rule in SonarQube Runner.
( I have deleted the "test scope" of logback-classic from the Maven pom.xml)
The results that I have examined , logback.xml had been set at the time of SonarQube Runner run .

https://github.com/SonarSource/sonarqube/blob/6be98b208a59535af4cbbcfff3af0d49d111a6bd/sonar-batch/src/main/java/org/sonar/batch/bootstrapper/LoggingConfigurator.java

Is it possible to set my own log in java-custom-rules plugin?
If it can be done in , I want to know how.